# What is the right way to evaluate $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \left(-t\sqrt\lambda + \lambda e^{t/\sqrt\lambda} - \lambda \right)$?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

The limit I’m working with is:

$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \left(-t\sqrt\lambda + \lambda e^{t/\sqrt\lambda} - \lambda \right)$$

Just applying the limit directly I guess we’d get: $-\infty$ because the dominating term is $-\lambda$. The second term gets multiplied by $e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda}}$ which goes to $0$ as $\lambda$ goes to $\infty$.

However, when we apply a Taylor expansion for $e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda}}$:

$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \left(-t\sqrt\lambda + \lambda \left(e^0 + \frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda} +\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda} \right)^2 +\frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda} \right)^3 +\ldots \right) -\lambda \right).$$

Multiplying the Taylor expansion out by $\lambda$ and after applying $\lambda\to\infty$ we have all the terms after $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda} \right)^2$ go to zero. The terms directly before $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt \lambda} \right)^2$ are canceled out by terms $-t\sqrt\lambda$ and $- \lambda$.

Therefore, all we’re left with is $\frac{1}{2}t^2$.

I guess the second approach to this problem is the correct approach just because it uses more math (???). Can someone tell me why the first approach is incorrect? Or I guess in general, if someone can point out a way to approach unclear limits, that’d be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the first approach is that $e^\frac{t}{\sqrt \lambda}$ doesn't go to $0$ as $\lambda$ goes to $\infty$, it goes to $1$. Thus both second and third term have order of growth of approximately $\lambda$.

Your second approach is correct, except you need to write a reminder for Taylor series (and fix typo in denominator): $e^\frac{t}{\sqrt \lambda} = 1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt \lambda} + \frac{t^2}{2 \lambda} + O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^{3/2}}\right)$, which gives us after substitution $\frac{t^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! In the first approach even if we have both the second and the third term have the same order of growth, we see that the limit of the overall expression would still be $\infty$, correct?

Comment: No, because they have different signs. In general, if you subtract two functions with equal growth orders, you can get function with the same growth order, or anything slower (and in this case we indeed get slower order of growth). For example, $x + 1$ and $x$ have the same growth order, but their difference is just a constant (so growth slower).

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, that makes so much sense...

Comment: I see, so the warning here is that we had two terms with the same growth order. It's hard to tell if subtracting them would really cause them to be zero or just something slower or something with the same growth order. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in such cases we need to analyse functions in more details than just check growth order.